# converting WMV to ASF using ffmpeg / expression encoder studio

Tags: ffmpeg, wmv

I am trying to understand how to convert WMV to ASF file using either ffmpeg or Expression encoder application.

Couldn't really figure out how to achieve that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

ASF and WMV are one and the same - ASF stands for Advanced Systems Format which is the container format used by WMV video files (and WMA audio files), so ASF files that contain video usually have a WMV extension.

Having said that you do not any conversion since there is only one format in your question ;-)